# Find the dimension of the vector space

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, modules

Let $R=\mathbb{Q}[x]$ and consider the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}
x-1&0\\
1-x&x^2
\end{bmatrix}$$

Let $M$ be the cokernel of the map $R^2 \rightarrow R^2$. Compute the rank of the $\mathbb{Q}$ vector space $\text{Hom}_R(M,R/(x^2))$.

I found that $M \cong R \oplus R/(x^2)$. I also know that $$\text{Hom}_R(M,R/(x^2)) \cong \text{Hom}_R(R,R/(x^2)) \oplus \text{Hom}_R(R/(x^2),R/(x^2))\\\cong R/(x^2) \oplus \text{Hom}_R(R/(x^2),R/(x^2))$$

The first factor $R/(x^2)$ has dimension two since it has basis $\{1,x\}$. How do I find the dimension of the second factor? Would the maps in this set have to be $1 \mapsto 1$, $x \mapsto x$ and $1 \mapsto x$, $x \mapsto 1$, so the dimension is also $2$? But the dimension of $R/(x^2)$ over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is likely different than over $\mathbb{Q}$. So I am unsure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\text{Hom}_R(R/(x^2), R/(x^2)) \simeq \text{Hom}_{R/(x^2)}(R/(x^2), R/(x^2))\simeq R/(x^2)$.

Comment: So the dimension should be $4$?Can you please explain the first isomorphism?

Comment: Yes, the total dim is $4$. It's true that $\text{Hom}_R(R, R)\simeq R$ (but not necessarily $\text{Hom}_S(R,R)\simeq R$ when $S$ is a subring of $R$.) The reason is simple: $R$ is the free module of rank $1$ over itself, so any homomorphism from $R$ to $M$ is determined by the image of $1$ in $R$. In particular, we have more generally $\text{Hom}_R(R, M)\simeq M$.

Comment: Can you please explain the first step? Why can you switch the $R$ and $R/(x^2)$? Why is the set of homomorphisms with each module considered over $R$, the same as over $R/(x^2)$?Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: When is it true that $\text{Hom}_R(M,M) \cong \text{Hom}_S(M,M)$ for some quotient $S$, like in your solution? Or in this particular case $M=S$?

Comment: Is it always true that for a quotient $S$, $\text{Hom}_R(S,S)=\text{Hom}_S(S,S)$?

Comment: Because the ideal $I=(x^2)$ acts trivially on $R/(x^2)$, therefore any $R$ homomorphism from $R/(x^2)$ to itself factors through $R/I$ action. $\text{Hom}_R(S, S)$ doesn't make sense in general: a subring $S$ of $R$ may not carry a natural $R$-action. It's difficult to characterize when $\text{Hom}_R(M, M)\simeq\text{Hom}_S(M, M)$. For example, $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb R}(\mathbb R, \mathbb R)$ is quite different from $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb Q}(\mathbb R, \mathbb R)$